# Gmail API not returning message body when mail has attachment

Tags: .net, gmail, gmail-api

I've been struggling with an unexpected behaviour from Gmail API.

Until now, I get the body of every mail using mail.Payload.Parts[0].Body.Data, which contains the message body in base64. In this case, the MimeType of the part is text/plain.

The thing is that when the mail I'm retrieving has an attachment, parts[0] MimeType is "multipart/alternative", and its body has only null fields.

How am I supposed to get the mail body if it has attachments?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892) can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution in [this site](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm).

> C# simplifies network programming in .Net framework. C# describes
>   various protocols using communication programming like Socket
>   communications , SMTP mail , UDP , URL etc. The System.Net classes
>   uses to communicate with other applications by using the HTTP, TCP,
>   UDP, Socket etc. In the previous program we saw how to [SMTP email
>   from C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm) describes how to send an email with text body . Here we
>   are sending an email with an attachment.

Here is the sample code provided,

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using System.Net.Mail;
>
> namespace WindowsApplication1
> {
>     public partial class Form1 : Form
>     {
>         public Form1()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
>                 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
>                 mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
>                 mail.To.Add("to_address");
>                 mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
>                 mail.Body = "mail with attachment";
>
>                 System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
>                 attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
>                 mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
>
>                 SmtpServer.Port = 587;
>                 SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
>                 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
>
>                 SmtpServer.Send(mail);
>                 MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

You can also refer to the official [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) from the documentation, here the in-depth discussion about the api was introduced together with sample code and step by step set-up process.

For further reference, you can visit [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279953/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachments-using-smtpclient-sendasync).